# counting months between two days in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, one of which is a date column. I'm interested in creating a new column which contains the number of months between the date column and a preset date. For example one of the dates in the 'start date' column is '2019-06-30 00:00:00' i would want to be able to calculate the number of months between that date and the end of 2021 so 2021-12-31 and place the answer into a new column and do this for the entire date column in the dataframe. I haven't been able to work out how i could go about this but i would like it in the end to look like this if the predetermined end date was 2021-12-31:

df =

```
  |start date  months
 0|2019-06-30     30
 1|2019-08-12     28
 2|2020-01-24     23
```

Comment: Please give [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What would be the number of months for the following pairs of dates: 2020-01-30 and 2020-02-01,  2020-01-01 and 2020-01-31, 2020-01-31 and 2020-03-01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `np.timedelta64`:

```
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-12-31')
df['start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start date'])
df['month'] = ((end_date - df['start date'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).astype(int)
print(df)

  start date  month
0 2019-06-30     30
1 2019-08-12     28
2 2020-01-24     23
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that *start date* column is of *datetime* type (not *string*)
and the reference date is defined as follows:

```
refDate = pd.to_datetime('2021-12-31')
```

or any other date of your choice.

Then you can compute the number of months as:

```
df['months'] = (refDate.to_period('M') - df['start date']\
    .dt.to_period('M')).apply(lambda x: x.n)
```

Comment: Crucial difference (at least for me):
@NYC Coder and Valdi_Bo solutions will both return month=1 as difference between end_date = '01 Feb 2021' and '01 Jan 2021'. 
But for end_date = '01 Feb 2021' and '15 Jan 2021' NYC Coder will return month=0 and Valdi_Bo 1. I required the latter, thanks Valdi_Bo .